# Generating test data that spans days

Tags: activerecord, factory-bot, faker

I would like to have ActiveRecord objects to run tests against that span several days.

For example, I want x number of Posts over the last x days so that I can calculate the average rating for posts posted yesterday. This way I know it didn't include tests from posts in the previous days.

Would I have to seed the database to do this or am I writing bad tests? :)

Answer (score 0):

Take the following simplified example where your `posts` table has the `rating` column and a `created_at` column.

You can 'seed'/setup your test to mimic this, without needing to actually seed your development database for this.

```
let(:post_one) { Post.create(rating: 5, created_at: Time.now) }
let(:post_two) { Post.create(rating: 5, created_at: Time.yesterday) }

  it "calculates the average correctly" do
    expect "your expectation"
  end
```

Ideally make use of FactoryGirl rather than simply `Post.create`. You can then switch that out for `FactoryGirl.create(:post) { etc... }`